# Django - live filter of available model queryset

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the below form where a user can select a supplier and then the product from the supplier.  However currently when selecting the product it lets the user choose from all available products (from all suppliers).

How can I constrain this so that after the user selects the supplier the user can only choose products from that supplier?

Form:

```
class SupplierOfflineAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):

    supplier_list = Supplier.objects.all()
    supplier = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=supplier_list, empty_label=None, to_field_name='name')

    class Meta:
        model = SupplierAccount
        fields = ['supplier', 'product']
```

Models:

```
class SupplierAccount(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'supplier')
```

Comment: You need javascript for this. If you google it it returns tons of results, I just randomly post one here: http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2011/02/how-to-implement-two-dropdowns-dependent-on-each-other-using-django-and-jquery/